# Marginal likelihood: Why is it difficult to compute in this case?

Tags: bayesian, marginal-distribution, variational-bayes, bayes-rule

I have been reading up a bit on generative models particularly trying to understand the math behind VAE. While looking at a talk online, the speaker mentions the following definition of marginal likelihood, where we integrate out the latent variables:

$$
p(x) = \int p(x|z)p(z)dz 
$$

Here we are marginalizing out the latent variable denoted by z.

Now, imagine `x`are sampled from a very high dimensional space like space of all possible images of a given size but the prior `p(z)`is a unit Gaussian distribution. I am trying to understand why this would be difficult to evaluate considering `p(z)`is one dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z$ is still fairly high dimensional, typical values might range between 16 and 1000. This is still much lower than the dimension of $x$, which might be on the order of 10000 to 1 million. $p(z)$ is a standard *multivariate* gaussian, with identity covariance.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But in this talk there is only a single latent variable where the prior is a unit Gaussian. I am wondering why the integral is then still difficult to compute.

This also comes up in this Stanford talk (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5WoItGTWV54&t=2525s) at 31.12. However, the speaker does not really specify what the problem is with this integral.

Comment: @Luca I don't see anywhere where the lecturer claims $z$ is only one dimensional. I agree in that case, the integral can be tractably evaluated.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I must have got myself confused.